# Apache x86 and PHP x64

Tags: php, apache, x86, 64-bit

I've tried to run PHP x64 with Apache x86 and I have this error :
`Cannot load ... php7apache2_4.dll into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`.
Does it mean that I cannot use PHP x64 (64-bits) with Apache x86 (32-bits) ?

Comment: Why does that not sound like it would not and should not work to you.

Comment: PHP 7 is compiled for 32 bit architecture as well as 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot run the x86 executable with x86_64 libraries at the same time as they are different architectures and contain different instruction sets.

Comment: Good to know. But what I don't understand is that it works with Nginx 32-bit with CGI. What's the difference ?

Comment: When using CGI the PHP interpreter runs as a seperate process, If you run PHP as an apache module they both have to be compiled using the same architecture and even the same compiler and linker. When run as an apache module Apache calls the PHP interpreter like it was loading a .dll or .so because thats what it is doing

Answer (score 0):

I beleive, that

VC%  x86 implies, 32 bit PHP version.

VC%  x64 implies, 64 bit PHP version.